# Apply join on two result set - Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have query that gives me the documentid

```
select documentid from tbldocumentbyclient
where tbldocumentbyclient.isactive = true
and applicationid = '000116'
```

result:

Another query that give me the following result

```
SELECT  documentcategory,documentcategoryid, string_agg(documentid::text, ',')   as documentid
                        FROM  tbldocumentmaster 
                        where accounttype = 1 and usertype= 'INDIVIDUAL'
                        group by documentcategory,documentcategoryid
                        order by documentcategoryid;
```

result :
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Now,Can someone please suggest me how to get CategoryName that is not associated with any documentid

For Above case my result should be following.

1. DP Proof - 134 not available in first result
2. Address Proof Permanent - row 4.. not a single id available in documenid result

Here this are the documentcategory that is not associate with any document id

Comment: any document with `pplicationid = '000116'`?..

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name.. followed suggestion.. thks

Answer (score 2):

I think a simple join between your two tables should do the trick.  The logic here is if a document category from `tbldocumentmaster` really has no document IDs which match to anything in the `tbldocumentbyclient` table then the join should filter it off, leaving behind those categories which do match.

```
SELECT t1.documentcategory
FROM tbldocumentmaster t1
LEFT JOIN tbldocumentbyclient t2
    ON t1.documentid = t2.documentid
WHERE t2.isactive = true          AND
      t2.applicationid = '000116' AND
      t1.accounttype = 1          AND
      t1.usertype = 'INDIVIDUAL'  AND
      t2.documentid IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim,   it gives me the total 6  categoryname that is associate with documentid. i want to extract only those two categoryName that are not available in my first query result.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT distinct documentcategory,documentcategoryid
FROM  tbldocumentmaster m
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbldocumentbyclient d on d.documentid = m.documentid 
where accounttype = 1 and usertype= 'INDIVIDUAL'
and m.documentid is null 
and applicationid = '000116'
group by documentcategory,documentcategoryid
order by documentcategoryid;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,but  it show blank result.  i want to extract only those two categoryName that are not available in my first query result.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested but you can try this query:

```
SELECT  documentcategory,documentcategoryid, string_agg(documentid::text, ',')   as documentid
                        FROM  tbldocumentmaster 
                        where accounttype = 1 and usertype= 'INDIVIDUAL' and documentid not in (select documentid from tbldocumentbyclient where tbldocumentbyclient.isactive = true and applicationid = '000116')
                        group by documentcategory,documentcategoryid
                        order by documentcategoryid;
```